# send array of data as post to django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to send post request through a form to django views so as to use it to retrieve data from database on next page (action page). I am not getting the data on second page however.

I have tried to use array in the name and assign array value in the form. I tried a for loop of values and names as well. However no data is received at the second page.

The form to send post request:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'cartpage' %}" id="formcart">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <script>
            for(var i=0;i<prods.length;i++){
                document.write('<input type="gone" name="cartitems[]" style="display: none;" value="prods[i]" />');
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

Trying to get post data and the array elements on the second page in views.py:

```
def cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            cartitems = request.POST.getlist('cartitems')
        except (KeyError):
            raise

    firstval = pionizedb.objects.filter(id__contains=cartitems[:1])

    context = {
        'firstval': firstval,
    }

    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

alert({{firstval}}); in html page should return first value of the array.

Comment: @Sayse its firstval. It was a typo when posting here.

Comment: Fair enough, but that still isn't going to be the first item, it will be a queryset, you'd need `first()` perhaps to get a single object, does that queryset return any results?

Comment: @Sayse first() cannot be used. It gives "'list' object has no attribute 'first'" error